# How to calculate for the ln of a given number?

Tags: javascript, math

Good day all.

The google scientific calculator lets you calculate the ln of a given number.

**examples:**

> ln(1) = 0
>
> ln(2) = 0.69314718056

I've been trying to figure out the equation used by it to arrive at the answer. Any leads would be welcome.

I'm bad at math as you can tell. :(

Comment: That's a "logarithm", which is the power to which you have to raise some number (called the base) to get the original number. The base-2 logarithm of 8 is 3, because 2^3 = 8. "ln" refers to the "natural" logarithms, whose base is Euler's number *e* - an irrational number that shows up in all kinds of exponential growth in nature.
 Fractional logarithms are defined for numbers that aren't exact powers of the base, but there's no simple equation for calculating them; you can only approximate them by summing a number of terms from an infinite series.

Comment: @Kama, I'm confused. Are you asking what "ln" stands for, or how to use the Math.log() function, or what the algorith is for calculating the natural log of a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ln x` gives you the natural logarithm of `x` (or the value of `y` that makes the equation `e^y = x` true, where `e` is [Euler's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29))

```
Math.log(2);
```

The result will be:

```
0.6931471805599453
```

The log() method returns the natural logarithm (base E) of a number.

Note: If the parameter x is negative, NaN is returned.

Note: If the parameter x is 0, -Infinity is returned.

Comment: Is the OP really asking something this simple, or is he asking the algorithm for computing natural logarithms?

Comment: I interpreted this question as the OP not knowing what ln stands for, or what it's used for.  Based on his tag of javascript, I gave a javascript answer.

Comment: OMG! I've passed by Math.log a million times already :(. I should never be trusted with math stuffs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to verify the value for yourself, as some kind of programming exercise, the classical formula for the [natural or Neperian (Napier's) logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) is

```
ln(a)=limit(n -> inf) n*(root(n,a)-1),
```

so start with

```
n=1, a=2
```

and loop

```
n=n*2, a=sqrt(a),
output n*(a-1)
```

until some kind of convergence is reached. This will break down at some point due to the limits of floating point numbers, the repeated square root converges very fast towards 1.

---

The traditional definition without using the exponential function is via the integral

```
ln(a) = integral( 1/x, x=1..a)
```

where you can use the trapezoid or Simpson method of numerical integration to get increasingly more accurate results.

---

From the integral formula one gets via the geometric series the power series of the logarithm. A series based formula that will converge a little faster than the direct power series starts with the identity

```
ln(2)=ln(4/3)-ln(2/3)=ln(1+1/3)-ln(1-1/3)
```

from

```
a = (1+x)/(1-x)  <==>  x = (a-1)/(a+1).
```

Using

```
ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+x^5/5-+...
```

the even powers in the above difference cancel, and

```
ln(1+x)-ln(1-x)=2*x*(1+x^2/3+x^4/5+...),
```

So for the computation of ln(2) initialize

```
x=1/3, xx=x*x, n=1, xpow=1, sum=0
```

and loop

```
sum+=xpow/n, xpow *= xx, n+=2
output 2*x*sum
```

again until some kind of convergence is reached.